# OR-Tools: How I can not cum wait time from depot to first exit moment?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, routes, or-tools

I am working at scheduling problem where I have N employees driving vehicles to visit M client homes with concerted dates.

The problem I'm seeing is that total time for each vehicle includes wait time from depot to the moment for exiting to arrive to first concerted date in first location to visit. For example, if time window for vehicle 0 work day is (8AM, 19PM) and first date is 3 (9.15AM):

```
Route for vehicle 0:
0 Time(09:10, 09:10) -> 3 Time(09:15, 09:15) -> 7 Time(12:00, 12:00) -> 11 Time(16:35, 16:35) -> 0 Time(17:31, 17:31)
Time of the route: 571min
```

My expected route time would be 501min, I don't want to sum 70min wait time from 8AM to 9.10AM. How could I accoplish this?

Thank you in advance! I hope that @Mizux can help me :)

**EDIT WITH CURRENT SOLUTION:** Keeping track of total route minutes and only driving time for can comparing both:

```
# Data
time_matrix=[
[0,350.8,556.1,272.5,401.7,319.4,306.1,521.2,569.4,502.4,722.5,742.1],
[275.4,0,243.5,200.9,404.8,436.4,139.7,279.3,256.8,189.8,409.9,468.6],
[419.6,182.4,0,338,541.9,573.5,283.9,239.4,177.2,73.6,250.2,308.9],
[115.4,245.3,442.8,0,372.4,291.5,289.8,370,446.1,388.2,608.3,614.7],
[391.3,443.9,608.6,410.2,0,292.9,527.5,539.6,615.7,586.8,782.9,747.8],
[248.9,412.8,609.2,351.8,300.1,0,415,478.5,554.6,554.6,774.7,686.7],
[207.7,115.5,320.8,268.1,462.2,378.6,0,356.6,334.1,267.1,487.2,545.9],
[419.5,220.6,199.4,304.1,449.2,507.6,322.1,0,76.1,257.6,306.3,309.9],
[478.8,241.6,135.1,379.5,524.6,583,343.1,75.4,0,208.7,242,245.6],
[346,108.8,134.9,264.4,468.3,499.9,210.3,170.7,148.2,0,309.2,367.9],
[576.8,330.9,229.1,495.2,699.1,730.7,404.2,374.4,299,230.8,0,333.9],
[681.4,444.2,277.6,586.3,706.6,765,545.7,302.8,238.6,335.4,207.8,0]
]
ttw = [(0,660),(0,660),(0,660),(60,75),\
(120,135),(90,105),(180,195),(240,255),(285,300),\
(480,495),(510,525),(510,525)]
services_duration = [0,0,0,90,45,60,30,150,45,30,60,45]
NUM_VEHICLES = 3
MIN_ORDERS_BY_VEHICLE = 3 # minimum 2 orders by vehicle
RELATIVE_START_TIME = 8 # 8AM start work day

from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['time_matrix'] = time_matrix
    data['time_windows'] = ttw # time windows with concerted dates
    data['time_service'] = services_duration # service time for each order
    data['num_vehicles'] = NUM_VEHICLES 
    # we start from initial routes for trying to optimize them
    data['initial_routes'] = [
        [3,7,11], # order vehicle 0
        [4,6,10], # order vehicle 1
        [5,8,9] # # order vehicle 2
    ]
    # vehicles starts and ends from/to same location
    data['starts'] = [0, 1, 2]
    data['ends'] = [0, 1, 2]
    data['breaks'] = [(360, 360, 120), (360, 360, 120), (360, 360, 120)]
    return data

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
    count_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('count')
    travel_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('travel')
    total_time = 0
    driving_time = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        i = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            travel_var = travel_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            if i == 0: # store wait time until first exit moment in order can substract it from total route time later
                first_wait_time_depot = solution.Min(time_var)
            count_var = count_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            plan_output += '{0} Time({1}, {2}) -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                    "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(*divmod((RELATIVE_START_TIME*60)+solution.Min(time_var), 60)),
                                                    "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(*divmod((RELATIVE_START_TIME*60)+solution.Max(time_var), 60))
                                                    )
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            i+=1

        
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        travel_var = travel_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        count_var = count_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        plan_output += '{0} Time({1}, {2})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                    "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(*divmod((RELATIVE_START_TIME*60)+solution.Min(time_var), 60)),
                                                    "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(*divmod((RELATIVE_START_TIME*60)+solution.Max(time_var), 60)))
        
        print('Orders by vehicle: {}'.format(solution.Min(count_var)-1))
        plan_output += 'Time of the route (with waiting and service times): {}min\n'.format(
            solution.Min(time_var)-first_wait_time_depot)
        plan_output += 'Time of the route (only driving time): {}min\n'.format(
            solution.Min(travel_var))
        print(plan_output)
        total_time += solution.Min(time_var)-first_wait_time_depot
        driving_time += solution.Min(travel_var)
    print('Total time of all routes: {}min'.format(total_time))
    print('Total driving time of all routes: {}min'.format(driving_time))
    return {'driving_time': driving_time, 'total_time':total_time}
    
def main():
    """Entry point of the program."""
    data = create_data_model()
    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['time_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['starts'],
                                           data['ends'])
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['time_service'][from_node]+(int(round(data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]/60.)))
    
    def travel_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return int(round(data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]/60.))
    
    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)
    travel_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(travel_callback)

    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Time dimension.
    time = 'Time'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        660,  # allow waiting time
        660,  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero. Vehicles don't have to start to exactly start hour
        time)
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
    
    # Add only travel time dimension.
    routing.AddDimension(
        travel_callback_index,
        0,  # allow waiting time
        660,  # maximum time per vehicle
        True,  # Don't force start cumul to zero. Vehicles don't have to start to exactly start hour
        'travel')
    travel_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('travel')
    
    # Add time window constraints for each location except depots.
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
        if location_idx in data['starts']:
            continue # except depots
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
        # Set allowed vehicles for order
        routing.SetAllowedVehiclesForIndex([], index) # for the moment, all vehicles can visit any node

    # Add COUNT dimension constraint.
    count_dimension_name = 'count'
    routing.AddConstantDimension(
        1, # increment by one every time
        len(data['time_matrix'])+1,  # make sure the return to depot node can be counted
        True,  # set count to zero
        count_dimension_name)
    count_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(count_dimension_name)
    
    # enable empty route cost
    # https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/2067
    # https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/2161
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        routing.ConsiderEmptyRouteCostsForVehicle(True, vehicle_id)
        
    # Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        # force depot waiting time to zero
        time_dimension.SlackVar(routing.Start(vehicle_id)).SetValue(0)
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(data['time_windows'][vehicle_id][0],
                                                data['time_windows'][vehicle_id][1])
        
    # https://activimetrics.com/blog/ortools/counting_dimension/
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index_end = routing.End(vehicle_id)
        count_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftLowerBound(index_end,
                                              MIN_ORDERS_BY_VEHICLE + 1,
                                              100000)
    
    # set break time for vehicles
    
    node_visit_transit = {}
    for n in range(routing.Size()):
        if n >= len(data['time_service']):
            node_visit_transit[n] = 0
        else:
            node_visit_transit[n] = 1

    break_intervals = {}

    for v in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        vehicle_break = data['breaks'][v]
        break_intervals[v] = [
            routing.solver().FixedDurationIntervalVar(vehicle_break[0],
                                            vehicle_break[1],
                                            vehicle_break[2],
                                            False,
                                            'Break for vehicle {}'.format(v))
        ]
        time_dimension.SetBreakIntervalsOfVehicle(
            break_intervals[v], v, node_visit_transit
        )
    
    # Instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times.
    # to start the later and finish the earliest possible
    for i in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
        routing.AddVariableMaximizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))
        
    for i in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
        routing.AddVariableMaximizedByFinalizer(
            travel_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            travel_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))
        
    initial_solution = routing.ReadAssignmentFromRoutes(data['initial_routes'], True)
    print("Initial sol:\n")
    ini_times = print_solution(data, manager, routing, initial_solution)
    
    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(100)

    solution = routing.SolveFromAssignmentWithParameters(initial_solution, search_parameters)
    if solution:
        print("\nSolved sol:\n")
        end_times = print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
        print("\nTotal route minutes saved: {} min".format(ini_times['total_time'] - end_times['total_time']))
        print("Only driving minutes saved: {} min".format(ini_times['driving_time'] - end_times['driving_time']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

- When creating dimension don't "force cumul start to zero" I.e. set it `false` so vehicle don't have to start to exactly 8AM.
- You can force depot waiting time to zero: `time_dimension.SlackVar(routing.Start(vehicle)).SetValue(0)`
- You can use the Finalizer to start the later and finish the earliest possible

```py
    for i in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
        routing.AddVariableMaximizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))
```

EDIT:

Maybe your total time computation is wrong:

```
17:30 = 17*60 + 30 = 1051 min (from 0:00AM)
9:10 = 9*60+10 = 550 min (from 0:00AM)
```

and `1051 - 550 = 501 min` so it seems your total time (duration) computation is wrong...

Comment: thanks for answering! I already had the first point (don't force cumul start to zero on time dimension) and I have implemented the other two but the total time does not change.

Comment: Could you share the code ? How did you compute the total time ?

Comment: In "print_solution" method I can save solution.Min(time_var) only in first iteration in while loop. Later I can use this time for substracting it from total_time and plan_output vars but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do. One more question, could I keep track of travel times regardless of service or waiting time to compare only the "driving time" between my initial solution and the one solver does?

Comment: @david9ppo the Best is to create another travel only dimension i.e. with a callback only returning the `travel_time(from, to)`. i.e. you can have any number of dimension you want

Comment: I have just edited the post with my current solution for if it helps someone. Now, I can compare both route times: total (including waiting and service times) and only driving time (with a new travel_dimension).

Comment: @Mizux - Kazi here. routing.AddVariableMaximizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i))) has solve my problem.